# Inserting class into array results in weird access error

Tags: c++, xcode, exc-bad-access

I have defined an array of Tile objects in my header

```
Tile* tiles;
```

Then when I try to run functions on the class referred to in the array I get an error code saying EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

```
Tile* tiles[100][100];

for (int x=0;x<40;x++){
    for(int y=0;y<40;y++){
        tiles[x][y] = new Tile("tile_grass.png");
        tiles[x][y]->setPositionWorld(WorldPos::posWithPosition(x, y)); // error comes when this is ran
        this->addChild(tiles[x][y]);

    }
}
```

it seems to work fine if I use a normal pointer instead of an array of pointers, but I somehow have to store that the coordinates x and y hold that specific Tile object. How can I fix this?

Comment: This code looks good. Have you inspected `tiles[x][y]` in a debugger just before the faulting call?

Comment: Have you tried running it in a debugger? It will lett you examine variables to see what might be wrong.

Comment: I can't find anything out of the ordinary, which makes this so weird for it works if I do not use an array value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the code below and it worked very fine.

`

```
int* test[100][100];
for(int i=0;i<40;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<40;j++)
    {
        test[i][j]=new int(1);
        cout<<*test[i][j];
    }
}`
```

I reckon the problem is either in your constructor or the function call.

Comment: The visualstudio counterpart of the code seems to work fine too, so yes - the problem is not in the code itself.